# Converting a javascript Coding to Python Coding for Elfish Program

Tags: javascript, python, coding-style

I was looking for a program to do the elfish instances. Then I found this javascript code on the web.

```
var containsE;
var containsL; 
var containsF; 

function elfish(str){

    var checkLetter = str[str.length - 1]; 
    if (checkLetter === "e"){
        containsE = true;
    }
    else if (checkLetter === "l"){
        containsL = true; 
    }
    else if (checkLetter === "f"){
        containsF = true; 
    }
    // base case 
    if (str.length === 0)
        if (containsE && containsL && containsF){
            return true; 
        }
        else {
            return false; 
        }
    // if not base case     
    return elfish(str.slice(0, str.length - 1)); 
}

elfish("whiteleaf");
```

I wonder if it is possible to guide me to convert the code into python with an explanation?
the python version is 2.73

Comment: Could you explain what the desired output of the code should be?

Comment: Try it yourself. If you have a specific question, you can ask here.

Comment: Hi, so for the output, if the user enter the word waffles then it is a elfish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is nothing special to explain here. Python is very self-explaining in your case. To keep it readable i added parenthesis in the if statement. You could just leave them:

```
while True:
    # type in which word you want
    s = input() 
    # if some letter in your string was found
    if ('e' in s) and ('l' in s) and ('f' in s): 
        print('true')
    else:
        print('false')
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance and the explanation!

Comment: If this solved your question i would be glad if you mark it as answered. :)